# A regular expression to exclude a string of a specific length

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm fairly new to regex and got into a problem I can't wrap my head around.

I'm trying to exclude a string of a specific length in regex.

It goes as follows:

```
26.6921320 01.2023
```

I wanna exclude the "6921320" -> Its a variable string but always has a length of 7 characters.

I tried to do so with this:

```
(?:..(?!(\d.))[.\d])
```

Output would be:

```
Match 1: 26.
Match 2: 01.
Match 3: 023
```

Doesn't work as intended since I just tried my luck with limited knowledge.

I appreciate any help with explanation.

Comment: Does the numbers have to match only dates? or just numbers?

Comment: You need to replace `\b\d{7}\b` with empty string, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Currently you get those matches https://regex101.com/r/JrDm1Z/1 What should be the matches instead?

Comment: @Thefourthbird  Thanks for looking into it! I woulf need the exact same matches but with the first „2“ of 2023 included.

Comment: @muecas the match should be the date. In this case: 26.01.2023

Comment: @PGX Did you mean to match it like this? `\b(?:\d\d\.|\d{4})\b` https://regex101.com/r/GktTG2/1 Note that you can not "skip" a part of the match if you want a single match only.

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes! This is the way I wanted it. Thanks for the disclaimer aswell. I didnt knew that before. Helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows: `^([\d]{2})\.[\d]+\s([\d]{2})\.([\d]+)$`.

`([\d]{2})` will match the first to digits. `^\.[\d]+\s` will match the dot and the rest of the digits before the sspace. `([\d]{2})` will match the next two digits after the second dot and `([\d]+)` will match all the final digits. The patterns enclosed with `()` will be the one specified as "matches" in your prefered programming language.

**Edit**: reading the edited question (adding dots to the matches) the regex should be as follows: `^([\d]{2}\.)[\d]+\s([\d]{2}\.)([\d]+)$`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and I had something similar in mind with this.
It help. But yet there is a problem with it.

In this case it makes 3 Groups which are correct with the date and the dots.

The Match1 I get as an output is the full string though:

"Match 1: 26.6921320 01.2023"

The program that parses it outputs me the Match1 aswell instead of the groups.

Is there any way to correctly "match" what is now just a "group"?

Comment: All the languages i use always includes as first match the whole string matched. Do you want to exclude the whole match? What language are you using?

Comment: I currently use it in a program only. I will check which language it uses and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

To get matches only for the given example, you can use an alternation with word boundaries.

The pattern matches separate parts due to the alternation, as you can not skip matches in a single match only.

```
\b(?:\d\d\.|\d{4})\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `\d\d\.` Match 2 digits and `.`
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{4}` Match 4 digits
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fglOY4/1).